# Is there somewhere I can get the CSS for a Windows Styled Modal Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a modal box that would look like the Windows 7 modals.

For example, the notepad box.

I found this before somewhere but I never got the style and it looked really good. It has the resize feature which would be really good.

Is there somewhere I can get the images I need?

Comment: Those styles might be protected Copy Rights ...

Comment: Is microsoft using CSS for their compiled applications like notepad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tomatocart](http://www.tomatocart.com/products/store-demo.html) use an astonishing windows layer style for its admin section ...

You should inspect the code and try to get assets ...

Comment: You can try the demo store ... logins are admin/admin at http://demo.tomatocart.com/admin/index.php